# First order logic FOL translation help!

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I am allowed to use Prime$(x)$ and Even$(x)$, and quantifiers. I just wanted to make sure if I'm on the right track.

1. There is no greatest number: 
   $$\forall x \exists y(x<y)$$
2. Any number added to itself is even: 
   $$\forall x \mathrm{Even}(x+x)$$
3. Every even number is the sum of two primes numbers: $$\forall x (\mathrm{Even}(x)) ⟹ \exists y \exists z(\mathrm{Prime}(y) \land \mathrm{Prime}(z) \land x = y+z)$$
4. No square number is prime:
   $$\lnot \exists x \mathrm{Prime}(x \cdot x)$$
5. The result of multiplying an odd number by itself is always odd.

I have no exact idea of how to approach this one. 
Would it be "for all the $x$'s that are not even, the result is not even when $x$ is multiplied by itself"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say $\forall x ⟶ R$?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! It might be useful for you to check out this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour . Your question, as it is, is not formatted with mathjax, making it harder to read: to understand how to use mathjax use this https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: I meant real numbers. I should have used the symbol ℝ !

Comment: Ah, ok. I assumed by $R$ you meant $\mathbb{R}$. But $\forall x ⟶ \mathbb{R}$ doesn't quite mean 'for all real numbers'. Typically the way to say that is $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, does that seem familiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consequent in ($3$) has a free variable, namely $x$. This can be fixed by moving the parenthesis at the end of the antecedent to the end of the entire expression, so:

$$\forall x (\mathrm{Even}(x)) ⟹ \exists y \exists z(\mathrm{Prime}(y) \land \mathrm{Prime}(z) \land x = y+z)$$

Becomes

$$\forall x (\mathrm{Even}(x) ⟹ \exists y \exists z(\mathrm{Prime}(y) \land \mathrm{Prime}(z) \land x = y+z))$$
So that the universal quantifier can quantify over the whole expression.

For ($5$), the way you phrase it in English makes it somewhat unclear what you mean for it to say. Particularly with the word 'result'. Try:

$$\forall x (\lnot \mathrm{Even}(x) \implies \lnot \mathrm{Even}(x \cdot x))$$